# How to add an extra class in the following PHP code?

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]

That is my wordpresss plugin code

```
$html .= $userMeta->createInput( 'remember', 'checkbox', array(
    'value'         => isset( $_REQUEST['remember'] ) ? true : false,
    'label'         => !empty( $config['remember_label'] ) ?  $config['remember_label']   : __( 'Remember Me', $userMeta->name ),
    'id'            => !empty( $config['remember_id'] ) ? $config['remember_id'] :    'remember' . $uniqueID,
    'class'         => !empty( $config['remember_class'] ) ? $config['remember_class'] : 'um_remember_field',
    'enclose'       => 'p',
) );
```

I want to add a class on that `<p>` tag for give extra style specially display none..
`

Comment: anyone for suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$html .= $userMeta->createInput( 'remember', 'checkbox', array(
    'value'         => isset( $_REQUEST['remember'] ) ? true : false,
    'label'         => !empty( $config['remember_label'] ) ?  $config['remember_label']   : __( 'Remember Me', $userMeta->name ),
    'id'            => !empty( $config['remember_id'] ) ? $config['remember_id'] :    'remember' . $uniqueID,
    'class'         => !empty( $config['remember_class'] ) ? $config['remember_class'] : 'um_remember_field',
    'enclose'       => 'p class="myclass"',
) );
```